# Change default comments in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, twig, comments

Does anybody know how I can change what comments are generated when pressing the cmd + / shortcut in VSCode?

I use twig a lot and it's perfect for that because whenever I use the shortcut I get
{# #} but it's not very useful when I'm working in HTML so ideally I'd be able to have one option for a .twig file and another for a .html

Many thanks

Comment: the chars used are determined by the language definition file

Comment: You might have a look at the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax and let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Hi Mark. I've downloaded the extension but I'm not sure how I'd add the info that I would need to. For example I can see from the dox you've got: "python.brackets": [["{","}"],["[","]"],["(",")"]], so I thought using "html.comments.lineComment":[["<!--","-->"]], would work.

Comment: On my machine, in VSCode, `.html` and `.twig` have different comments. I am guessing you changed `files.associations` settings somewhere, so that the html file is detected as twig?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add new Keyboard shortcuts going into relative menu (**Ctrl+K** to open). You will notice that you can bind options to comment a line or block. I suppose the code to produce the comment is based on the file type you're working on and *I think it would be tricky to change its logic*.

You can actually find a complete keyboard shortcut for VSC here: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

While you can find more informations here as well: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings